# How to limit every user has 1000 records in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, architecture

I have 1,000,000 users, I want to store user's latest 1000 history.

So I want to limit our data always 1,000,000 * 1000, and I will create multiple tables with user id.

And I have much more users, I do not want scan every user's records limit in background, I think it's very ugly.

There are some features:

> - The table is store user's history
> - Limit every user only has 1000 rows in table
> - If user's new data to insert a row, discard the oldest row
> - Always 1000, allow non-real-time
> - 1,000,000 users
> - It's sociable, insert speed must fast.

Comment: or of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155053/can-we-limit-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table-in-mysql

Comment: You can do it programmatically

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried? You cannot expect people to design a mysql table without having done part of it yourself. SO is not a 'post requirements and get answers kthxbye' website :)

Comment: The problem is not "design table", but it is "how to limit". I hope do this logic fast and simple.

Answer (score 2):

Create a trigger that will truncate oldest row when the new one is inserted.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html

Comment: I know this, but this will be slow. I must "SELECT COUNT(*)" to check limit.

Comment: Well... there isn't really a way to define a table with such an automated behavior. You will need to count rows no matter if you choose to use triggers or program it into your application. If you're worried about performance, you can also use the same trigger to store number of rows per user in a separate table, then use it instead of `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Thanks, I think it's a better to do.